# How to remove unnecessary padding caused by resizable divs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, dom, tailwind-css

I have a div which I need to be resizable horizontally. Although on adding the css resize property the div gets an unnecessary padding. I'm not sure whether it's even possible or not after a few searches but it's really making the UI look hideous. Attaching the code and screenshot below for the div. I'm using React and Tailwind. Any help will be appreciated.

```
        <section 
className='bg-[#26252a] min-w-[285px] p-0 min-h-[70vh] overflow-scroll resize-x rounded-xl'
>

</section>
```

[image: screenshot]

I tried setting the `padding: 0 !important` but still it's of no use. If you see the box model on the right side you can see the component itself has no padding amount but it's still there.

Example JS fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Sam_Hawkz/n91gyu7x/1/#&togetherjs=l45GaPxBKQ

Comment: Could be anything is hard to debug with just your code and screenshot. Look at the other elements, maybe is some margin or something.
Best is if you can post an example in jsfiddle or something so we can see it in action.

Comment: @Medda86 here's a JS fiddle for the same - https://jsfiddle.net/Sam_Hawkz/n91gyu7x/1/#&togetherjs=l45GaPxBKQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your overflow set to `scroll`, which makes the ["user agents display scroll bars in both horizontal and vertical directions ... whether or not any content is overflowing or clipped."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#scroll) Change overflow to `auto`. Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ka6mo9jy/).